# how to use projections for nested arrays in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My schema looks like this:

```
new Schema (
users:[userSchema]
}

userSchema = new Schema ({
email: String,
companies: [companySchema]
})

companySchema = new Schema ({
dept:{
id: String,
desc: String
},
rooms: {
name: String,
location: String
});
```

I want to be able to find a particular department where I know its id and return just the dept. I am unable to figure out how I can use projections for this. I tried the below and several variants:

```
Model.findOne({“users.companies.dept.id”: “10},{users:{$elemMatch:{dept:{$elemMatch:{id:”10”}}}}});
```

All of which selects the entire user, not just the department.

My workaround is to find the user using findOne() and get the dept using some node code. Any insights are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection in MongoDB can only work at the "top" array level when matching arrays. To do anything more "on the server" you need to use the "aggregation framework" which is a bit more adept at doing this than the standard `.find()` queries have the ability to do:

```js
Model.aggregate(
  [
    // Match the document(s) that contain this match
    { "$match": { "users.companies.dept.id": "10" } },

    { "$project": {
      "users": {
        "$setDiffernce": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$users",
            "as": "user",
            "in": {
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": "$$user.companies",
                  "as": "comp",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$$comp.dept.id", "10" ] },
                      "$comp",
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                }},
                [false]
              ]
            }
          }},
          [[]]
        ]
      }    
    }}

  ],
  function(err,results) {

  }
);
```

That will "strip" any unmatched elements and any resulting "empty" arrays due to no matched elements within them. It is generally safe to use as long as the contained elements are all "unique" in their combined properties.

It's also quite fast, and just about as fast as a standard `.find()` operation due to only consisting of `$match` and `$project` stages. Which is basically what `.find()` does anyway. So apart from a "little" extra overvead there is no difference. And of course, less traffic is returned from the server per match.

You can also do this if your MongoDB server version is below 2.6 without those operators, or if your "dept.id" values are not unique within the inner arrays.

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        // Match the document(s) that contain this match
        { "$match": { "users.companies.dept.id": "10" } },

        // Unwind arrays
        { "$unwind": "$users" },
        { "$unwind": "$users.companies" },

        // Match to "filter" the array
        { "$match": { "users.companies.dept.id": "10" } },

        // Group back to company
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
               "_id": "$_id",
               "user_id": "$user._id",
               "userEmail": "$user.email"
           },
           "companies": { "$push": "$users.companies" }
        }},

        // Now push "users" as an array
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "users": { "$push": {
                "_id": "$_id.userId",
                "email": "$_id.userEmail",
                "companies": "$companies"
            }}
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
);
```

But all the use of `$unwind` there is horrible for performance, and you would be better off simply removing your unwanted items in your application code as you currently do.

So if your server supports it, then use the first option to take the load off your app and network transfers. Otherwise stick with what you are doing as it is likely faster.

Comment: Thank you - this was very educational! I'll start reading up on the aggregation framework

Answer (score 0):

I have this collection

```
> db.depts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55af5cefa894779dc40208e7"), "dept" : { "id" : 2, "desc" : "test" }, "rooms" : { "name" : "room", "location" : "test2" } }
```

and the below query returns only the `dept`

```
> db.depts.find({'dept.id':2},{'dept':1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55af5cefa894779dc40208e7"), "dept" : { "id" : 2, "desc" : "test" } }
```

So in moongose, it should be

`Model.findOne({“users.companies.dept.id”: 10},{“users.companies.dept”:1, “_id”: 0})`

Comment: I do not think this is analogous - you have to use $itemMatch for arrays